# How to get WFS from Geoserver localhost:8080 to OpenLayers localhost:1234

Tags: vector, localhost, openlayers, geoserver

I am trying to get the map of contiguous US that appears as a pre-installed topp:states layer in my local laptop installation of Geoserver 2.19.1.  I want it to appear as a vector layer on a localhost port.  I actually started with the openlayers example at  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html, and got that example to work nicely, appearing as it should at http://localhost:1234, but for other layers, taken from external websites.  With some effort I found the needed modifications that I expected to work for the Geoserver topp:states layer obtained from localhost:8080, but I just couldn't seem to make it appear at localhost:1234

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import View from 'ol/View';
import {Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style';
import {Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer';
import {bbox as bboxStrategy} from 'ol/loadingstrategy';

var vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  format: new GeoJSON(),
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
      'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=topp:states&'+     
      'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
      'bbox=24.9,-124.8,49.5,-66.0',
});

      
var vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)',
      width: 2,
    }),
  }),
});


var map = new Map({
  layers: [vector],
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new View({
    center: [-10000000,4500000.0],
    zoom: 4,
  }),
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?  If it is on a different port the GeoServer may need to be CORS enabled https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html#enable-cors  And is https correct?

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  I simply needed to enable CORS, like you say, and as your link points to.  This merely involved uncommenting two blocks of code in the web.xml file.  My original javascript was also incorrect, but what I now show in my question works.